# C# saving file as csv is not delimited correctly when viewed in Excel

Tags: c#, csv

I am using this code to convert my data into a csv file:

```
 var lines = new List<string>();

 IEnumerable<PropertyDescriptor> props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T)).OfType<PropertyDescriptor>();

 var header = string.Join(",", props.ToList().Select(x => x.Name));
 lines.Add(header);

 var valueLines = reportData.Select(row => string.Join(",", header.Split(',').Select(a => row.GetType().GetProperty(a).GetValue(row, null))));
 lines.AddRange(valueLines);
```

But when I view the .csv file afterwards, it looks like this:

[image]

So the file is not delimited correctly.

Everything is stored into one column.

The rows are correct however, but again - everything in one column.

I can however then in excel save the file again as "comma delimited Excel csv" and when I open the new file, it shows correct.

So how can I save the file (if not as csv) but instead directly within the correct file format?

Comment: The file is delimited correctly. The problem is how you opened the file in Excel - by double-clicking on the text file instead of using `Insert Data`. CSV is just a text file, not a well-defined file format. When you double click on a *text file*, Excel has no way of knowing what *decimal* separators and therefore what list separators are used. Instead of guessing, it uses the separators specified for the user's locale. Obviously, in your machine, the locale uses `,` as the decimal separator, so `;` is used as the list separator

Comment: What are you trying to do? Produce a file end users can open in Excel? Produce a standard CSV file to import to other applications and just occasionally open it in Excel? You can use a library like EPPlus, NPOI, ClosedXML to generate true `xlsx` files without Excel. You can save lists of objects to CSVs using a library like eg CsvHelper, which can use different separators *and* handle quoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel use CSV separator based on you region preferences. It seems that separator in your system is ';'. To set custom separator "," for file you need write

> sep=,

at first line, so your file must looks like this:

```
sep=,
Data1, Data2, Data3...
```

Comment: This is fully correct thanx